# Working on a requirement but I not sure what should be the right approach?

Tags: html, canvas

I am working on a requirement where I need to draw nodes on screen when i double click on the screen. When i select a particular node. Node should showup extra set of options. One of the option is +. When i click on +. It will create a child node this way. I can create nodes and subnodes with each time a select a node it shows me set of options. I am not sure which way to start.

I thought html5 canvas will be the right way to go.

But the nodes I create are not objects so I could not have events on them. What else do you guys think should be the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG fits your requirements perfectly. Consider using [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)